# Compound distribution with unknown distribution of its hyperparameter

Tags: probability, estimation, parameter-estimation

Suppose $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$, and $\sigma$ is another random variable in a sense that we only know that it is some *constant* random variable with finite support, i-e $\sigma \in [\sigma_\max, \quad \sigma_\min].$

**Question**
Is it plausible to consider $\sigma$ as uniformly distributed i-e $$\sigma \sim \mathcal{U}[\sigma_\max, \quad \sigma_\min]?$$

If No, then what could be the best we could do to estimate (or infer about) $\sigma$ by only knowing its maximum and minimum values?

Comment: It is plausible to consider any distribution for $\sigma$ as long as it takes positive values, of course. How to choose a prior distribution for $\sigma$ relies on the specific problem I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The true prior distribution on $\sigma$ could be strongly centered at any value within your range, or even take on any value in your range with probability $1$. Thus the only thing you can really do, if you don't have any guess for the prior distribution on $\sigma$, is give bounds on things you're trying to compute, for example in terms of the minimum and maximum possible values for $\sigma$.

Alternatively, people try to come up with "flat" uninformative priors. However this is tricky, because a seemingly flat prior might actually produce bias in the posterior if the prior isn't formulated correctly. I believe there is a supposedly "flat" prior for the variance of a Gaussian, but I'm not sure if it accepts a lower and upper bound. Look up priors on parameters for a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: What are your logical grounds when you say " I believe there is a supposedly "flat" prior for the variance of a Gaussian" ?

Comment: Harold Jeffries used the improper distribution $d\sigma/\sigma$, which is invariant under changes of scale. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy you meant this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior ?

Comment: @kaka : Not quite the same thing.  Look at Jeffreys' book. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This one? http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Probability-Classic-Physical-Sciences/dp/0198503687